# Automated instant local backups on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, backup

No, I don't want to use RAID at the moment, instead I want a software or a script which can constantly sync folders on one hard-drive to a second physical hard-drive on my PC or any other PC on my internal network.

And if that network PC is not available to schedule it to copy to it the next time it comes on.

The reason I need this kind of a solution is that as a family we have a network of PC's and collectively a lot of empty space on each other's computers that can be used for collective backups.

Another feature which would be largely appreciated would be if the space used for backup's can be protected from accidental deletion and can only be deleted by a passworded account or some other protected means.

Basically if the software would allow me to visualize all the space that could be reserved for backup's as one drive and allow for backup's to DVD's when the data crosses a particular limit I set. Seems like a dream backup strategy to me as this would allow me a rock solid backup setup in an automated fashion and that to without use of any additional resources. Any ideas on this? Would appreciate any sort of ideas which would throw some light on this issue.

Comment: In this question: http://superuser.com/questions/165828/backing-up-important-data
One of the comments talks about using rsync. I'm not sure if this will work for your purpose but it's worth a look.

Comment: but this is for UNIX based computers and I use windows and seems like a hassle to setup, would prefer something with GUI definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for can be handled by [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com). Excerpts:

> CrashPlan is FREE for personal use and automatically backs up your computers daily. You can back up to your own drives and other computers for free. Just download and install.
>
> ...
>
> **Multiple Backup Destinations**
>
> Backing up to multiple destinations ensures your files are protected in any situation. With CrashPlan you can back up to:
>
> - Any internal or external hard drive
> - A friend's computer or another computer you own
> - CrashPlan Central, our online backup service with unlimited storage
>
> ...
>
> CrashPlan Backup Software - FREE!
>
> - CrashPlan lets you back up your computer to local drives and other computers anywhere in the world.
> - Includes 30 day FREE trial of CrashPlan Central

Comment: I realize that their heavy use of FREE makes this sound like a serious ad. I'm actually not assiociated with them and actually haven't started using their product. Best of luck!

Comment: sounds good but does let you combine all the storage space you have on your network or at least show it to you as one drive even though its not?

Comment: I have no idea, unfortunately.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Each computer you install the client on will show up as a separate location to backup to assuming all the clients are connected using the same CrashPlan account.